# Umbraco 8 - hide Member Groups

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

Can anyone advise if and how I can hide the Member Groups folder within Members in Umbraco 8 for a specific user group?

Failing that, can I give users access to the members section but prevent member group deletion?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an API point of view this can be done now with events so it would be up to you at a granular level to decide what rules are applied to hide properties. You can subscribe to the event EditorModelEventManager.SendingContentModel and modify the outgoing model which means you can add/remove tabs/properties, and pretty much whatever you want. If you wanted to pursue that without modifying the core It would also be possible to create a package to have some UI to control these rules if you wanted.

Comment: Hi,
still figuring this out, think I need to use something like
EditorModelEventManager.SendingMemberModel += EditorModelEventManager_SendingMemberModel;
private void EditorModelEventManager_SendingMemberModel(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext sender, EditorModelEventArgs<Umbraco.Web.Models.ContentEditing.MemberDisplay> e)
 {
      //do my thing
}

but with EditorModelEventArgs<Umbraco.Web.Models.ContentEditing.MemberGroupDisplay>

Comment: Accepting your answer as it led me to the solution, will post full solution when I can, in case anyone else finds it useful